# NoSuchTableException in DbUnit Oracle

Tags: java, junit, dbunit

I am trying to use dbunit with oracle and have a test case as below. When I try to run the below code it gives me. I am not sure where am i wrong here. Can someone please help

org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: INVOICE_STATUS_TYPE
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData(DatabaseDataSet.java:278)
    at org.dbunit.operation.DeleteAllOperation.execute(DeleteAllOperation.java:109)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)

```
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.dbunit.DBTestCase;
import org.dbunit.PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester;
import org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConfig;
import org.dbunit.dataset.IDataSet;
import org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlDataSet;
import org.junit.Test;


public class MyTest extends DBTestCase{

private FlatXmlDataSet loadedDataSet;
public MyTest() {

    super();
    System.out.println("TEST TEST");
    System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_DRIVER_CLASS, "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" );
    System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_CONNECTION_URL, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=vp1.qa.nsc.com)(PORT=2186))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=FADBBD1E)))" );
    System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_USERNAME, "nscdba" );
    System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_PASSWORD, "dscdbapwd" );
    System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_SCHEMA, "INVOICE" );
}


@Override
protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception {

    //return new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new FileInputStream("dataset.xml"));

    loadedDataSet = new FlatXmlDataSet(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dataset.xml"));
    System.out.println(loadedDataSet.getTableNames().length);
    return loadedDataSet;
}

@Test
public void testStatus() {
    System.out.println("Hey...");
    Assert.assertTrue( true );
}

protected void setUpDatabaseConfig(DatabaseConfig config) {
    config.setProperty( DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES, true );
}
}
```

Comment: So, does the table INVOICE_STATUS_TYPE exist in the database FADBBD1E?

Answer (score 2):

With Oracle, ensure that DB credentials are all in UPPER CASE, i.e.:

```
System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_USERNAME, "MYUSERNAME" );
System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_PASSWORD, "MYPASSWORD" );
System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_SCHEMA, "INVOICE" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you invoke "org.dbunit.operation.DeleteAllOperation.execute()" ?

If the table does exist, take a look at how you get the dbunit connection.

```
private IDatabaseConnection getConnectionUsing(Connection con,
        String username) throws SQLException, DatabaseUnitException {
    // oracle schema name is the user name
    IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(con,
            username.toUpperCase());
    DatabaseConfig config = connection.getConfig();
    // oracle 10g
    config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY,
            new Oracle10DataTypeFactory());
    // receycle bin
    config.setProperty(
            DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_SKIP_ORACLE_RECYCLEBIN_TABLES,
            Boolean.TRUE);
    return connection;
}

private IDatabaseConnection getConnectionUsing(Connection con)
        throws DatabaseUnitException {
    return new DatabaseConnection(con);
}
```

If you run tests against oracle, the db username need to be offered as schema name. If you run tests against hsqldb, do not offer username.

Hope this helps.